# Redux Toolkit middleware does not work to handle successful asynchronous actions

Tags: typescript, next.js, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I've integrated into my Next.js app some of my own middleware into the Redux-Toolkit store using `configureStore`. Middleware is designed to handle asynchronous actions such as fetchAccounts/fulfilled to update navigation state and user accounts. Despite adding them via

```js
getDefaultMiddleware({
  thunk: {
    extraArgument: updateNavTabMiddleware, updateSelectedAccountMiddleware
  },
  serializableCheck: false,
}),
```

they seem to be greyed out. I used `console.log` to debug incoming actions, but I don't see the expected logs. How to properly debug middleware in the Redux-Toolkit, and is there a way to ensure that they are actually executed in the expected order before the reducers?

In the documentation I read that the Redux-Toolkit `configureStore` API automatically adds the Thunk middleware during store creation, so it should typically be available with no extra configuration needed.

Middleware

```js
import { PayloadAction, Dispatch, MiddlewareAPI } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const updateSelectedAccountMiddleware = (store: MiddlewareAPI) => (next: Dispatch) => (action: PayloadAction<Account[] | number>) => {
  console.log(action);
  if (action.type === 'accounts/fetchAccounts/fulfilled' && Array.isArray(action.payload)) {
    const savedAccountId = getSelectedAccountIdLS();
    const savedAccount = action.payload.find((account: Account) => account.id === Number(savedAccountId));

    store.dispatch(setSelectedAccount(savedAccount || action.payload[0]));
  }

  if (action.type === 'accounts/deleteAccount/fulfilled' && typeof(action.payload) === 'number') {
    const state = store.getState();
    let newAccounts = state.accounts.data;

    if (state.accounts.selected.id === action.payload) {
      newAccounts = state.accounts.data.filter((item: Account) => item?.id !== action.payload);
    }

    saveSelectedAccountIdLS(newAccounts[0].id);
    store.dispatch(setSelectedAccount(newAccounts[0]));
  }

  return next(action);
};
```

Store

```js
export const makeStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {
      visual: visualReducer,
      user: userReducer,
      accounts: accountsReducer,
      topics: topicsReducer,
      channelsHistoryRecords: channelsHistoryRecordsReducer,
      competitors: competitorsReducer,
      words: wordsReducer
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: {
        extraArgument: updateNavTabMiddleware, updateSelectedAccountMiddleware
      },
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
  })
}

// Infer the type of makeStore
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>
// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch']

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
export const useAppStore: () => AppStore = useStore
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are only passing these middleware functions to the thunk middleware as its "extra argument". While it is true that Redux-Toolkit applies Thunk middleware by default, the Thunk middleware's `extraArgument` doesn't add any additional middleware to the store. The `extraArgument` is made available on `createAsyncThunk`'s `thunkAPI` of the [payloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) function.

If you are trying to add additional middlewares to your store then they should be appended/prepended to the middleware of the store when it's created.

See [configureStore middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware) and [getDefaultMiddleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) documentation for complete details.

Add your `updateNavTabMiddleware` and `updateSelectedAccountMiddleware` middleware functions to the store's middleware when creating/configuring it.

Store

```js
const reducer = {
  visual: visualReducer,
  user: userReducer,
  accounts: accountsReducer,
  topics: topicsReducer,
  channelsHistoryRecords: channelsHistoryRecordsReducer,
  competitors: competitorsReducer,
  words: wordsReducer
};

export const makeStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false })
        .concat(updateNavTabMiddleware, updateSelectedAccountMiddleware),
  });
};
```

Comment: This helped, but when using the stricter MiddlewareAPI, Dispatch and PayloadAction types I am encountering a typing error due to a type mismatch between the provided and expected middleware type. The error indicates that the type returned by my middleware callback function is not compatible with the type that configureStore expects from the function. Specifically, the error indicates a type mismatch between two different sets of middleware, where one of them is an array of ThunkMiddleware and my custom middleware functions, and the other is the expected set of Redux Toolkit middleware.

Comment: @AlexanderGnetov *Where* are you seeing an array of Thunk middlewares? I see potential issue with your `updateSelectedAccountMiddleware` middleware using the un-typed plain `Dispatch` type instead of your typed `AppDispatch`, and its very specific action payload type. You may not need to explicitly type these as RTK *should* be able to infer them. Maybe this would be better addressed as a new SO post for the specific middleware typing issue you have now.